# largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers. "JAVA"

Tags: java

I realize that this question has been asked before, but I didn't like any of the answers. They all looked like they were more complex then need be. I prefer to keep things as simple as possible.

I wrote my code and from what I see there is no reason it shouldn't work? Am I missing anything? I don't get an error, but I don't get any results.

public class LargestPalindromeProduct {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome
    // made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
    //
    // Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit
    // numbers.

    long product;
    for (int i = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
        for (int j = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
            product = j * i;
            if (reverse(product)) {
                System.out.println(product);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}


private static final boolean reverse(long value) {
    long result = 0;
    while (value != 0) {
        result *= 10;
        result += value % 10;
        value /= 10;
    }
    return (result == value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a fairly major bug in your inner loop,

```
for (int j = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
```

should be

```
for (int j = 999; j >= 100; j--) {
```

And since

> They all looked like they were more complex then need be. I prefer to keep things as simple as possible.

Let's rewrite `reverse`;

```
private static final boolean reverse(long value) {
    String str = String.valueOf(value);
    return str.equals(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString());
}
```

Finally, you're only breaking the inner loop. Either use `System.exit` or a labelled `break`.

```
outer: for (int i = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
    for (int j = 999; j >= 100; j--) {
        long product = j * i;
        if (reverse(product)) {
            System.out.printf("%d * %d = %d%n", i, j, product);
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I cant believe i missed the error in the for loop. I looked over this for a long time before I decided to post here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a logical error in your algorithm. You suppose that when `reverse(product)` is true, then you have the LargestPalindromProduct, given that the two loops are descending from 999 to 100. This is not necessary correct. Suppose for example, that the first palindrome found by your program is (i=999)*(j=3). The result is 2997 (this is not a palindrome, but suppose it is). How can you be sure that there are no bigger palindromes, for i=998 and j=997, for example?

Comment: The loops don't iterate simultaneously. At the beginning, the value of the outer loop `i` is fixed to 999 and the inner loop `j` goes from 999 to 100. So, the program will reach the case (i==999 and j==3) before reaching the case (i==998 and j==997)

Comment: Makes sense. I'll add a maxNum variable and take out the break.

if (reverse(product) && product > max) 
 max = product;